# Help with Bishop's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning", Q.4.16

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

> Q.4.16. Consider a binary classification problem in which each observation $x_n$ is known
>   to belong to one of two classes, corresponding to $t = 0$ and $t = 1$, and suppose that
>   the procedure for collecting training data is imperfect, so that training points are
>   sometimes mislabelled. For every data point $x_n$, instead of having a value $t$ for the
>   class label, we have instead a value $\pi_n$ representing the probability that $t_n = 1$.
>   Given a probabilistic model $p(t = 1|φ)$, write down the log likelihood function
>   appropriate to such a data set.

To  me this question seems trivially simple, which usually means I'm doing something wrong. Is there anything else to this question besides substituting $t_n$ for $\pi_n$ in the classification formulas?

Comment: no, you're good.

Comment: You might want to craft a proof to convince yourself.  That way you get something out of the exercise.